# FQL returns only one photo

Tags: facebook-fql

I use this query:

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE owner=$friend_id;
```

It works fine, but for some users(that has more than 1 photo) this query returns only 1 record.

Then i tried this query:

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE owner=$friend_id LIMIT 10;
```

But returned result is the same - only 1 record.

Permissions :

user_activities,
user_photos,
friends_activities,
friends_photos,
publish_stream

What i have to do to get correct result for anyone user??

Comment: Are they definitely the owner and not a tag? Have you tried running a similar api call in the developer tools at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=788085506%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the friend's privacy settings for the albums and photos he/she shares/uploads.

Also, I noticed that the `owner` field in the `photo` table is not indexable but it is in the `album` table and hence you may need to use something like:

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE owner = XXXXXX AND aid IN (
    SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = XXXXXX
)
```