# FQL retrieves empty data set but API explorer does not

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are some similar questions but I believe this is a problem on its own.

I'm using Facebook SDK for Android to get my friends photos listed on the device, and when I use Graph Explorer I actually get the data I wanted but inside my app I get only **ONE** result.
I first tried to use this FQL

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE owner = me();
```

But then I found that table `photo` is not indexable ([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156984/fql-returns-only-one-photo)), so I tried with table `album`

I even tried with my own photos using this FQL

```
SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE owner = me() AND aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me())
```

I have all necessary permissions `(user_photos,friends_photos,user_friends)`

Also I have tried to add some limit, like 2 or 25 to check if that could be the problem.

But still nothing! :(

Any of you Facebook gurus have any idea what is my problem?

Thanks in advance

### Answer // edited

Oh well... It seems that 5 hours of waiting is not enough for Facebook servers to propagate the changes and that by adding those permissions I wrote above I managed to get what I needed.

So answer would be (just for test phase, for the real thing you need to wait for Facebook servers to propagate):

1. Go to Graph API explorer
2. Open FQL tab (or if you are using Graph API stay where you are)
3. Click the drop down menu in the right top corner where it says *Applications*
4. Choose your app (it should be *Graph API explorer* by default)
5. Click **Get Access Token** button
6. You will see that you are missing some privileges indeed
7. Select what you need
8. Approve it
9. Test your app again in you development environment
10. Voila